# Autocomplte search both name and code

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

*places.json* as follows

```
[{"CC":"XNR","CN":"Aabenraa"},{"CC":"AAH","CN":"Aachen"},{"CC":"XOA","CN":"Aalbaek"},{"CC":"AAL","CN":"Aalborg"},{"CC":"QFA","CN":"Aalsmeer"}]
```

*CN* represent contry code and *CN* represent contry name

```
$(".typeahead").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
        $.ajax({
            url: "places.json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function(v,i){
                    var text = v.CN;
                    if ( text && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) ) {
                        return {
                                label: v.CN.concat(' (',v.CC,')'),
                                value: v.CC
                               };
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

How can I implement my code to search both country name and country code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only checking the country name in `matcher.test()`. you should check country code too

update following if (condition)

```
if ( text && ( !request.term || matcher.test(v.CN) || matcher.test(v.CC) ) ) {
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: @TobySpeight, thank you for the information. i have updated my answer.